# How to split excel file based on Specific Column

Tags: c#, excel

I have example data like this (in Excel)

Name       Place
A          JKT
B          JKT
C          CGK
D          JKT
E          CGK
F          BBK
G          JKT
H          BBK
I          BBK
J          BBK
K          CGK
L          CGK

I've been given 3++ files that contain data like the example, and the step is , i must combine the files first into 1 excel file, than the output that i already combine must be split into many excel file based on Place.

Ex : in that data has 3 different places, so it will create 3 different files for JKT,CGK and BBK

The code i tried to combine

```
xlApp = new excel.Application();
 xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
 xlWs = xlWb.Sheets[1];
 xlRange = xlWs.UsedRange;

 row = xlRange.Rows.Count;
 col = xlRange.Columns.Count;
 fulldata = new string[row][];

 for (int i = 0; i < fulldata.Length; i++)
 {
    fulldata[i] = new string[col];
    //MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
     {
         try
         {
            fulldata[i][j] = xlWs.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].value2.ToString();
         }
         catch (Exception ee)
         {
             fulldata[i][j] = "";
         }
      }
 }

//create new excel file for combined data

xlApp1 = new excel.Application();
xlWb1 = xlApp1.Workbooks.Add();
xlWs1 = (excel.Worksheet)xlWb1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlRange1 = xlWs1.UsedRange;

newFileRow = xlRange1.Rows.Count;
newFileCol = xlRange1.Columns.Count;

//Combine
if (newFileRow == 1)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
       {
           xlWs1.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = fulldata[i][j];
       }
   }
}
else
{
   for (int i = newFileRow+1; i < row + newFileRow; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
       {
           xlWs1.Cells[i, j + 1] = fulldata[count][j];
           count++;
        }
     }
}

//Split ExcelFile
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
       {
           //insertcode here
       }
   }
```

The problem is , the data has more than 40 Place , so i dont know the effective way to split it, because if i use the hardcode mode it will be not efficiency and hard to read.

Hardcode = defines variable for 40 different places, define excel.Application for 40 different excels, and use if for 40 ++ different places

Expected result (from example):
1st excel : JKT.xlsx

```
Name       Place
A          JKT
B          JKT
D          JKT
```

2nd excel : CGK.xlsx

```
Name       Place
C          CGK
E          CGK
K          CGK
```

3rd excel : BBK.xlsx

```
Name       Place
F          BBK
```

Any help will be appreciated and grammar correction

Comment: You started with Excel automation via C#, so you can use it further to compeate the task. Just read the file line by line with the Range object and copy each line to the appropreate Excel file..

Comment: hmmm but it contains more than 40 Code Place so it wont be effecient or maybe will take long time if i must to use if statement for all the code place

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use query? After you read the file, put the `ORDER BY` Statement.

```
SqlCommand cmd = "SELECT NAME, PLACE FROM namaTabel ORDER BY PLACE ASC"; 
cmd.fulldata();
```

Comment: it can be used without database? .-.

Comment: Where do you get the data from?

Comment: My supervisor, why?

Comment: No. I mean, is it from a database, or user input or something else.

Comment: from user input

Comment: after you read the date, save it in db temporarily, and then display it with query. You cant sort the data before it enters the db.

Comment: You can do it quite fast & elegant using MS Access. It hase import & export Excel VBA methods and with the query above and similar queries